# Nuxt.js `this.$route.params.id` is undefined when navigating from direct link

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a strange problem when I am using Nuxt.js with SSR mode, for fetching data in page components I am using nuxt `fetch()`, this works fine when I am navigating between nuxt-links but if I refresh the page or visit the specific page from direct link, in some cases `this.$route.params.id` is undefined, I can't figure out what  is causing this problem
File structure inside pages folder

[image]

---

`pages/blogs/_id/index.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div class="container-padding">
     {{singleBlog}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { getSingleBlog } from "@/utils/api";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      singleBlog: {},
    };
  },

  async fetch() {
    this.singleBlog = await getSingleBlog(this.$route.params.id);
  },
};
</script>
```

`utils/api.js`

```js
import axios from 'axios'
let baseUrl = 'https://myurl'

/* get single blog  */
export const getSingleBlog = async (blogId) =>{
  let req =  await axios.get(`${baseUrl}/api/blog/${blogId}`)
  return await req.data
}
```

---

Here is my `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
DirectoryIndex
Options -Indexes
# Forcing all incoming requests to HTTPS. 
# HTTPS is required for PWA. If you don't want PWA feature you can deisable next 2 lines

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomen.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) "http://127.0.0.1:3000/$1" [P,L]
```

Comment: `in some cases` is pretty hard to debug. Do you have a [repro] of it? The issue should come from somewhere else than the shown code IMO.

Comment: Also, what do you call "direct link"? `nuxt-link` or `a` tag?

Comment: For example `https://mysite/blogs/164`

Comment: The code that you showed should work perfectly fine.

Comment: Hey, mind sharing more info that could help you find the issue?

Comment: @kissu Hi, You are right, the given code works perfectly on the heroku host, Maybe I have an error in the htaccess file that affects the entire application. P.S I have updated my question and add htaccess file

Comment: Where is the `.htaccess` file located? Not sure that I get it. Also, what do you use for `target` in your `nuxt.config.js` file?

Comment: `.htaccess` file is located at the root directory, in `nuxt.config.js` target is `server`

Comment: So, do you have the issue if you `yarn build && yarn start` locally on your computer?

Comment: Your `pixelId` is doomed, you'll need to either ask an admin to properly delete it or to generate a new one since this can be found in the history as of right now (public).

Comment: @kissu, So thanks, when I am using yarn build && yarn start, I do not face the same problem, most likely the problem is in the server configuration, here I will write a updates when I find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because on direct visit it's called at **server-side** but navigationg with `nuxt-link` calls it at **client-side**.

`this` is not available at **server-side**

*fetch is called on **server-side** when rendering the route, and on **client-side** when navigating. according to [Nuxt Docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/components-glossary/pages-fetch)*

Comment: `fetch()` is available in both server and client and allows for the usage of `this` as far as I know. https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle#server Are you sure about what you're saying about `this`?

Comment: @kissu, on the image at the top of the page you sent `server-side`, it says it can be used as long as context is passed as argument and in the image below where `client-side` is, it says `this` is available here and not on the above image. I'm not 100% sure but that is what the docs say.

Comment: So, I tried `target: server` + `ssr: true` in a `/blogs/_id.vue` file using the `fetch()` hook and it properly returns the value `12` if I try to reach `/blogs/12` with `this.$route.params.id` in it.